# foreach with key and array

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I have an array with

```
array(2) {
  ["bar_id"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  ["foo_id"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "56"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "46"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "61"
  }
}
```

How to get an array with `[["2","56"],["1","46"],["3","61"]]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$foo = $arr['foo_id'];
$bar = $arr['bar_id'];
$result = array();
$count = count($foo);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $result[] = array($bar[$i], $foo[$i]);
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: OK for this, but I have 11 and more keys (not only foo_id and bar_id)… so there is no "magic" function to rotate my array.

Comment: You could easily get the array keys (Using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and if you can find out or already know the number of elements in each of the sub-arrays, you should be able to do it.

Comment: Yes I know, I will do my own function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$parent_array = array(
                       'bar_id' => array('2','1','3'),
                        'food_id' => array('56','46','61')
                      );


$bar_array = $parent_array['bar_id'];
$food_array = $parent_array['food_id'];

$new_array = array();


for($i= 0 ; $i<count($bar_array); $i++)
   {
         $new_array[$i] = array($bar_array[$i],$food_array[$i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$food = $arr['food_id'];
$bar = $arr['bar_id'];
$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <count($food); $i++) {
    $result[] = array($bar[$i], $food[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array[0]); $i++){
    $new_array[] = new array(
        $array['bar_id'][$i],
        $array['foo_id'][$i],
    );
}
```